# Vue.js: How to prevent browser from going to href link and instead only execute the @click method?

Tags: javascript, url, vue.js, preventdefault

So I have a link in my application like this:

```
<a href="/threads/my-first-thread/" @click="openThread">My first thread</a>
```

At the moment, when I click the link, the browsers follows the href link and also executes the "openThread" method. I want to keep the link in there so that it shows the user where a click is going to bring him to, but I don't want the browser to actually follow the link (I open a lightbox instead and change the url with pushState). I want it to only execute the given method.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are looking for [.prevent](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) modifer.

```
<a href="/threads/my-first-thread/" @click.prevent="openThread">My first thread</a>
```

Comment: `.stop` stops propagation. What the OP needs is to prevent the default action (`.prevent`).

Answer (score 8):

See [Event Handling](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) in the guide:

> **Event Modifiers**
>
> It is a very common need to call `event.preventDefault()` or `event.stopPropagation()` inside event handlers. Although we can do this easily inside methods, it would be better if the methods can be purely about data logic rather than having to deal with DOM event details.
>
> To address this problem, Vue provides event modifiers for `v-on`. Recall that modifiers are directive postfixes denoted by a dot.
>
> `.stop`
>
>  `.prevent`
>
>  `.capture`
>
>  `.self`
>
>  `.once`
>
>  `.passive`

So:

```
<a href="/threads/my-first-thread/" @click.prevent="openThread">My first thread</a>
<!-- -------------------------------------^^^^^^^^                    --->
```

...or of course, accept the event parameter and call `preventDefault.`

[Live Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arqfgc73/) (since Stack Snippets don't allow off-site links).

Comment: `@click.prevent` won't work as of today. You still will be moved to an href link.

Comment: @AlexanderKim - [Yes, it does](http://jsfiddle.net/arqfgc73/). See the linked documentation, and that fiddle demonstrating it.

Comment: My mistake, sorry. I forgot to mention - i was trying it with `<router-link>` and it didn't work.

Comment: @AlexanderKim - I haven't used `router-link`. Looking at the docs, it's not clear that it works with `@click` -- it seems to handle hooking the handler itself, and just lets you control the [event that triggers navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#event). If you need a callback that can prevent routing, probably worth posting a question about the right way to do that... Happy coding!

Comment: Hi @AlexanderKim I am having the same issue now, did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if anyone needs to use `vue router`, here is the solution:

```
<router-link
  :to="{ name: 'routeName' }"
  :event="''"
  @click="functionName"
>
```

[Taken from vue-router git issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/916#issuecomment-297424249).